# Cannot upgrade to expo SDK > 40 in terminal

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, expo, app-store

So I am trying to submit a react native app with the eas/expo commands in the prompt. I have deleted and re-installed node, npm, eas, and expo many times, yet when I am doing the "eas build" command it still says I should have expo SDK > 40 for it to work.

when I do the "node --version" command it says v16.15.1

it says "eas-cli/0.53.1 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.1" for eas version

5.4.9 for expo version

8.11.0 for npm version

I have been running these commands to update them:

"npm install -g npm@latest

npm install --global expo-cli@44 (I tried many version)

sudo npm i -g expo-cli

n stable

n latest.  "

Any guidance is greatly appreciated on how to get my current version to > 40.

Best Regards,
Evan

Comment: the expo-cli version is not the same as the expo package version. look in your package.json for the expo package / sdk version. here's how you upgrade that https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the Expo SDK version in `package.json` files as below

```
  //...other packages...
    "color": "4.0.1",
    "expo": "^43.0.0", <= Expo SDK version
    "expo-av": "~10.1.3",
```

Check the app Expo SDK version, if lower than 40, you need to upgrade it to your preferred version.

Upgrade instruction - https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough